# pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "development" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

In trying to push my database from my `development.sqlite3` file to my Heroku app, I encountered the following error message:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "development" failed: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
pg_restore: [archiver] input file is too short (read 0, expected 5)
psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
 !    Heroku client internal error.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
 !    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new
```

I am new to Heroku and can't figure this one out.  Hoping it's something simple I'm overlooking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, sqlite isn't intended to be used in production. In fact, Heroku doesn't support using sqlite, so you'll need to switch to Postgres if you want to use your app with Heroku: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4#write-your-app.

The specific error you're getting is because your heroku app is to connect to port 5432, which is utilized by Postgres by default and is not used by sqlite. However, since you don't have a PG server to connect to on localhost, you app is failing  with that error.